# Neo4j with graphql: unable to fetch self reference type

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-graphql-js

I have simple neo4j & graphql example. Here is my typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = `
        type Employee {
            eid: ID!
            name: String!
            title: String!
            email: String
            reportees: [Employee] @relation(name: "REPORTS_TO", direction: "BOTH")
        }

        type Query {
            getAllEmployees: [Employee] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (a:EMP)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(b:EMP) RETURN a, b")
            getEmployee(name: String): [Employee] @cypher(statement: "MATCH (e:EMP) WHERE e.name contains $name RETURN e")
        }
`;
```

I'm able to fetch all data except **reportees**, which is always empty. What am I missing here? Here is sample cypher create scripts I used for this example.

```
CREATE (gma:EMP {eid:"1", name: “George Hill”, title:”President", email:”g.hill@test.com"})
CREATE (aba:EMP {eid:"2", name: “Anna Syntel”, title:”Manager”, email:”Anna.s@test.com"})
CREATE (noa:EMP {eid:"3", name: “Nagz Hello”, title:”Developer”, email:”n.hello@test.com"})
CREATE
        (aba)-[aa:REPORTS_TO]->(gma),
        (noa)-[bb:REPORTS_TO]->(aba)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query only returns the two EMP nodes, and doesn't return the relationship. Try the query

`"MATCH (a:EMP)<-[r:REPORTS_TO]-(b:EMP) RETURN a, r, b"`